# Get list of apps or permissions for a user in Office 365

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Requirement:
I want to get the list of all apps ( Microsoft or third party applications ) that a particular O365 user has installed or has given some permissions to. I would like to fetch all the permissions/scopes that the particular app asks for.

Google provides an API to do the similar functionality using the /users/xxx/tokens API - 
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list

Is there any similar API for MSGraph or Azure AD for Office 365 users to get their list of apps and related permissions

Comment: Can you clarify a few things? You mentioned "a particular O365 has installed" - do you mean "has granted consent"? Then you mentioned "or is using" - usage would be a different thing, perhaps an user has consented to an app but he/she is not using the app anymore. Then you mentioned "all the permissions/scopes that the particular app asks for". That would also be a different thing: an user could have consented to an app but then the app could have changed the required permissions.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the user has granted some permissions to the application.  I want the list of all such apps for a user.

Comment: If the app has changed the required permissions, wouldn't it ask the user to give the rest of the permissions again ( via a consent screen or something ). In any case, I would like to get the permissions that the user has provided the app.

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to do this -

First get all the oauth2PermissionGrants objects provided by a user to any of the applications.
Use the following API to do this - 
https://graph.windows.net/{tenantDomain}/users/{userID}/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6

Then use the clientID mentioned in the repsonse to get the details for the application

https://graph.windows.net/{tenantDomain}/servicePrincipals/{clientID}?api-version=1.6

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-apps-permissions-consent

You can use *Get-AzureADUserOAuth2PermissionGrant* to see a list of all applications a user has granted access to along with the permission scopes, then use *Get-AzureADServicePrincipal* to find the name of the application. Here's an example searching based on the user's UPN.

Load all granted applications for a user.

```
$grants = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString first.last@domain.com | Get-AzureADUserOAuth2PermissionGrant
```

Get the name of an application from the list above

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $grants[0].ClientId
```

Example

```
$grants = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString first.last@domain.com | Get-AzureADUserOAuth2PermissionGrant

> $grants[5] | fl


ClientId    : <snip>
ConsentType : Principal
ExpiryTime  : 4/27/2016 11:15:39 AM
ObjectId    : <snip>
PrincipalId : <snip>
ResourceId  : <snip>
Scope       : User.Read user_impersonation
StartTime   : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

>
> Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $grants[5].ClientId

ObjectId                           AppId                             DisplayName
--------                           -----                             -----------
<snip>                             <snip>                            ExampleAppName
```